# Unsupported marks in jTag widget?

Tags: support, guitars, jtab

Is there any way to mark palm muting or natural harmonics in jTab tabulature system?

I asked this after reading that question [What are the various methods of tuning the guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/what-are-the-various-methods-of-tuning-the-guitar)

Comment: Do x's not work for mutes?

Comment: Mutes can be also marked with P.M above tab. After editing, before save, preview doesn't show tabs (only jTab code). Maybe it will work with just adding it like code (true type font) to mark some N.H or mentioned X.

Answer (score 1):

Palm muting or natural harmonics go beyond what jTab is capable of - you can check the full reference of what is possible here:  http://jtab.tardate.com/#notation